Is there any way to change CMEK key from vertex ai workbench instance?
I want to change the CMEK key for workbench notebook instance in Vertex AI. I have checked the this doc but it's not help me clear my issue.

Currently it is not possible to change the existing CMEK key of the Vertex AI notebook VM disk. However, there is a feature request filed for the same. You can vote for this feature by clicking the +1 and STAR mark to receive updates on it.
